# Need an array formula in excel for unique sequenced values

Tags: arrays, excel

I need a formula to group sequenced data and then calculate the sum of each sequence. so I need an array formula to calculate "each sequence" & "sum" column without "sequence" column as shown in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: You can use a Pivot Table for this. You can group data by `Sequence` and `Name` and sum up the field `Score`

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if it can be done with an array formula.

Comment: Which version of Excel do  you have? Do you have the UNIQUE function available?

Comment: 2019, No. I have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with offset ranges:

In F2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$18<>A$1:A$17,ROW(A$2:A$18)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

in G2:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$18<>A$1:A$17,ROW(A$2:A$18)),ROW(A1))):INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$2:A$18<>A$3:A$19,ROW(A$2:A$18)),ROW(A1))))
```

In other words, you're detecting where each block starts and ends.

[image]

I've only tested these formulas in Microsoft 365 - you probably need to array-enter them in Excel 2019.

Comment: Thank you! You are a real problem solver :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for an array formula. A simple `SUMIF` will do it:

```
G2: =SUMIF(Sequence,ROWS($1:1),Score)
```

and fill down as needed.

Where

[image]

There is no requirement that the `Sequence` column be visible. It does need to be the same size and dimension as the `Score` column, but could be located anyplace, and hidden.

Comment: but I need to do it without "sequence" column.

Comment: @M.Matador Oops. Missed that requirement.  Why not just hide the column somewhere else on the worksheet?

Comment: @M.Matador How about a User Defined function written in VBA?

Comment: Hiding column would be last resort if couldn't find better way.

Comment: VBA makes my workbook complicated. I don't need this.

Comment: @M.Matador Then I suggest you hide the `Sequence` column.